# Vue js : can't change saved password in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, vuejs2

i have an issue, i have a login page to my website, and when i'm connecting and click on "Save password" on Google Chrome, i can't change my password anymore:

My password field auto fill with the password of the mail, and when i try to enter another one (with the email still in the email field), but it keeps re auto fill with the old password (every second or so), here is my password input:

```
<input class="form-control" required name="password" :placeholder="$gettext('Password')" type="password" v-model="password">
```

I don't have any code or function that change the password model.

If someone have an idea from where it can come, i'll be really thankful.

Comment: Can you share link to the page?

Comment: I have the same issue with vuejs 2.6.3, i can fix the problem using 2.5.22.